# Using Column Alias in Another Column

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I want to use an alias column as another column in the select clause.

```
select col_1/col_2+col_3 as new_col,
       new_col+10 as new_col_2
from table
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use sub query to achieve this:

```
select new_col, new_col + 10 as new_col_2
from (
    select col_1 / col_2 + col_3 as new_col
    from table
) t
```

Comment: How would you select all columns from the original table plus the columns from the outer select, but exclude the columns in the inner select clause?

Comment: @wipphd Can you please provide the actual expected output by using the some sample table with columns?

Comment: @wipphd If it answers your original question, you may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)